# Models are not being generated by Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I go through the Entity Data Model Wizard, select an existing database and select two tables (invoice_header and invoice_line).  After completing the wizard, I get an empty Diagram, and I don't see any models associated with the tables I selected.  InvoicesModel is the name I typed in when going through the wizard.  I was expecting to also see models for the two tables.  There were no errors, and I've done this several times, using several different databases and tables, with the same result.  What causes this?

UPDATE:  I'm having the problem on a Teradata instance.  This problem does not occur when I use tables on a SQL instance.

[image: Models]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Issues with Teradata provider](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/13.11/webhelp/EntityProviderEdmWizard.html#notincluded)

> Database Objects Not Included in the Model
>
> ADO.NET Entity Framework can't work with types that cannot be used in tables. Therefore, >database objects that can be included in the model are subject to the following >restrictions:
>
> Table columns must be based upon only supported types.
> Stored procedures must have only parameters of supported types. If any parameter has >unsupported type, the stored procedure is excluded from the model.
> Tables must have an inferable entity key.
> Entity Framework requires every entity to have at least one key column. Usually entity key >is inferred based on the table's primary key. If a table has no primary key, the entity key >includes all NOT NULL columns. If a table has neither primary key nor NOT NULL columns, it >is excluded from the model.
>
> Entity Framework also requires the Primary Keys to not contain binary columns. If a primary >key fails in this condition, the entity is excluded from the model.

To test, I created a simple table with 2 fields, and the wizard successfully created the models